# Error when parsing FedEx Multidimensional Arrays with N-Level in Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array

FedEx web services return the following multidimensional array:

```
array(2) {
  ["Meta"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Code"]=>
    int(200)
    ["ErrorMessage"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  ["Data"]=>
  array(6) {
    ["Errors"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["ShipmentId"]=>
    string(12) "801000933796"
    ["Destination"]=>
    array(6) {
      ["Addr1"]=>
      NULL
      ["Addr2"]=>
      NULL
      ["City"]=>
      string(10) "PARSIPPANY"
      ["State"]=>
      string(2) "NJ"
      ["PostalCode"]=>
      NULL
      ["Country"]=>
      string(2) "US"
    }
    ["EstimatedDelivery"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["DeliveredTime"]=>
    string(25) ""
    ["Packages"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["TrackingNumber"]=>
        string(12) "xxsssdfsds"
        ["Activity"]=>
        array(19) {
          [0]=>
          array(8) {
            ["Description"]=>
            string(9) "Delivered"
            ["Location"]=>
            array(4) {
              ["City"]=>
              string(10) "PARSIPPANY"
              ["State"]=>
              string(2) "NJ"
              ["PostalCode"]=>
              string(5) "07054"
              ["Country"]=>
              string(2) "US"
            }
            ["Time"]=>
            string(25) "2019-07-08T09:31:00-04:00"
            ["StatusCode"]=>
            string(2) "DL"
            ["StatusTypeCode"]=>
            NULL
            ["StatusDescription"]=>
            string(9) "Delivered"
            ["Signatory"]=>
            string(7) "name"
            ["ProofOfDelivery"]=>
```

Working with Laravel PHP Everything works ok extracting single line values, but I cannot find the way to extract N-Level values like the one displayed inside [Packages]

I tried the following on controller:

```
        $events['Description'] = $response['Data']['Packages']['Activity']['Description'];
        $events['City'] = $response['Data']['Packages']['Activity']['Location']['City'];
        $events['State'] = $response['Data']['Packages']['Activity']['Location']['State'];
        $events['Country'] = $response['Data']['Packages']['Activity']['Location']['Country'];
        $events['Time'] = $response['Data']['Packages']['Activity']['Time'];
        $events['StatusCode'] = $response['Data']['Packages']['Activity']['StatusCode'];
        $events['StatusTypeCode'] = $response['Data']['Packages']['Activity']['StatusTypeCode'];
        $events['StatusDescription'] = $response['Data']['Packages']['Activity']['StatusDescription'];
        $events['Signatory'] = $response['Data']['Packages']['Activity']['Signatory'];
        $events = array();
        foreach($response['Data']['Packages'] as $data)
        {
            $events[] = $data;
        }
    }

    return view('ship2b/trackresults', compact('$events'));
```

and the view:

```
@foreach ($data as $row)

    {{ $row['Activity']['Location']['City'] }}
    @endforeach
```

But the system displays error at controller in every

```
$response['Data']['Packages']['Activity'];
```

of course it works if I placed [0] eg:

$response['Data']['Packages'][0]['Activity']['Description'];

but it will not iterate through ['Packages'] and only will retrieve first ['Activity'] value.

My desire output would be something like:

```
@foreach ($data as $row)

    {{ $row->Activity->Location->City }}
    {{ $row->Activity->Location->State }}
    {{ $row->Activity->Location->Country }}

    @endforeach
```

for each Package Activity information. Thanks!

Comment: Can you add your desired output to the question?

Comment: @matticustard ok.

Comment: I think I have figured out what you want, but do you want all events lumped together, or do you want them grouped by package?

Comment: @matticustard updated!. its a fedex tracking activity, what I need is to display the information based on timestamp of each record. Right now I can access information using [0], [1] but taking into consideration it can have [N] levels thats the part I dont know how to solve it.

Comment: Okay, I'll post an answer and you can tell me if it's what you want.  Then we'll go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Controller**

```php
$packages = [];

foreach($response['Data']['Packages'] as $p => $package) {
    foreach($package['Activity'] as $a => $activity) {
        $packages[$p]['Activity'][] = [
            'Description' => $activity['Description'],
            'City' => $activity['Location']['City'],
            'State' => $activity['Location']['State'],
            'Country' => $activity['Location']['Country'],
            'Time' => $activity['Time'],
            'StatusCode' => $activity['StatusCode'],
            'StatusTypeCode' => $activity['StatusTypeCode'],
            'StatusDescription' => $activity['StatusDescription'],
            'Signatory' => $activity['Signatory'],
        ];
    }
}

return view('ship2b/trackresults', compact('packages'));
```

**View**

```html
@foreach ($packages as $package)

    @foreach ($package['Activity'] as $event)

        <div>{{ $event['Description'] }}</div> 
        <div>{{ $event['City'] }}</div>
        <div>{{ $event['State'] }}</div>
        <div>{{ $event['Country'] }}</div>
        <div>{{ $event['Time'] }}</div>
        <div>{{ $event['StatusCode'] }}</div>
        <div>{{ $event['StatusTypeCode'] }}</div>
        <div>{{ $event['StatusDescription'] }}</div>
        <div>{{ $event['Signatory'] }}</div>

    @endforeach

@endforeach
```

Comment: My pleasure!  Good luck.